# Unable to test component that uses translation pipe (The pipe 'translate' could not be found)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, ngx-translate

I have a component that uses ngx-translate for localization. The basic unit test to create the module does not work. It fails with the following error:

```
PatientDataComponent should create FAILED
   [ERROR ->]{{ 'patient.information' | translate }}
  </p>
  The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<p>[ERROR ->]{{ 'patient.information' | translate }}</p>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/PatientDataComponent.html@1:2
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true, ngParseErrors: [ The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<p>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/PatientDataComponent.html@1:2 ] })
```

The application is able to switch languages; thus ngx-translate seems to work. Except in my unit test. The test code looks as follows:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PatientDataComponent } from './patient-data.component';

describe('PatientDataComponent', () => {
  let component: PatientDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PatientDataComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PatientDataComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PatientDataComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

What do I need to do to resolve this error and make the component testable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your testBed config add in `imports` the `TranslateModule` like you do in your appModule or the module where the component is declared. for example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [PatientDataComponent],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: I18nHttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
}).compileComponents();
```

Maybe you have other translation config.

Comment: Thank you; I also needed to add the HttpClientModule to the import and to define the export ```function I18nHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `assets/i18n/`, '.json');
}``` - then this worked :-)

Comment: Can you explein me better @PatrikGfeller ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mock pipeline:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: "translate"
})
export class MockTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    public name: string = "translate";

    public transform(query: string, ...args: any[]): any {
        return query;
    }
}
```

This mock pipeline can be in the spec file above the describe OR you can create a mock folder with translate-mock.pipe.ts and then inport the MockTranslatePipe in the spec file (so you dont need to write this code for every spec file).

- then add the MockTranslatePipein declarations:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [GenericChecklistComponent, **MockTranslatePipe**],
      imports: [MatMenuModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: TranslateService, useFactory: translateServiceStub }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the module into your testbed (like you would for any other module, like HttpModule or RouterModule). E.g.:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'public/assets/i18n', '.json'),
            deps: [Http]
        })],
        declarations: [SidenavComponent] // declare the test component
    });
});
```